# XPS 13 9360 Intel GPU modesetting driver missing resolutions

Tags: xorg, display, intel, resolution

I have an XPS 13 9360 with Intel HD 620 GPU. After reading some stuff recommending to uninstall the deprecated (only used for old chipsets), **xserver-xorg-video-intel** driver and use the kernel embedded **modesetting**, I decided to go on with the task to get the advertised *better performance*.

After uninstall and first reboot everything seemed to work fine in the native resolution of the screen **1920 x 1980**. However after seeing in the display settings, I found out that some other resolutions were missing. Most notably the **1600 x 900** and some other (I believe mainly 16:9 type of resolutions).

Also please note that `xrandr` is not reporting these resolutions either and my OS is **Linux Mint 18.2** with kernel **4.10.0.26** ...

Anyone dealt with this before?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but with my 4K intel P530 iGPU. I was missing some resolutions as well including 1920x1080p.

I followed the directions [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr)

Go to the troubleshooting section and the first portion mentions adding unsupported resolutions.

You'll be using either **gtf** or **cvt** to get the modelines for a particular resolution.

From there you will use xrandr to set the new modes. There is a way listed to make it permanent via a udev rule but personally I use scripts.

Also I'd advise not to append *_60.0* after each only because some games just don't like the naming scheme (I had that issue with Minecraft, as soon as I saved a mode named 1920x1080 instead of 1920x1080_60.0 it was available in game without actually switching to 1080p in X.

Comment: So, it is a bug that should be fixed in the newer kernel versions?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I'm thinking it's a problem with the modesetting driver in the kernel so probably yes, maybe in the future. But for now just use either a udev rule, script at X startup or your .xinitrc to add the modelines you need and then it'll be maintenance free.

Answer (score 1):

Until now, resolutions such as 1600x900 not present in modeset driver (Linux kernel version: 4.11.0-14)

The funny thing is the kernel properly reports the resolutions with:
`grep . /sys/class/drm/*/modes`:

> /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/modes:1920x1080
>   /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/modes:1680x1050
>   /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/modes:1400x1050
>   /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/modes:1600x900
>   /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/modes:1280x1024
>   /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/modes:1280x1024
>   /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/modes:1440x900
>   /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/modes:1280x800
>   /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/modes:1152x864
>   /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/modes:1280x720
>   /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/modes:1024x768
>   /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/modes:1024x768
>   /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/modes:800x600
>   /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/modes:800x600
>   /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/modes:640x480
>   /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/modes:640x480
>   /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/modes:720x400
>   /sys/class/drm/card0-eDP-1/modes:1920x1080

For me the solution was a slightly modified version of @cory-t answer.
The commands that added the missing resolution where:

`xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode eDP-1 "1600x900_60.00"`

To persist the added config I added these lines to a file `45_extra-resolution` in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` to be run after X11 initialization process